# Angular - primeng ngfor multiple conditions for the same columns using ngif

Tags: angular, primeng

I am still a novice using angular and I was wondering if some can help me with the following or point me in the right direction.
I have the following code

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns" >
   <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData" >
       <td *ngFor="let col of columns"  (click)="changeButtonStatus();" >
          {{col.field == 'defect_target_completion_date'?  (rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'):rowData[col.field]}}   
       </td
   </tr>
</ng-template>
```

the code works fine but I need to add the following condition: if defect_target_completion_date is earlier than today's date then change the colour to red otherwise just leave it as it is.

I tried doing it in the component without success and when trying to add it as a second part of the statement I get compilation errors.

Thanks.

Comment: What element has to be changed to red? `<td>`?

Comment: Hi Adrita,  one of the 10 columns (Defect_target_completion_date) has to change to red if the date is less than today's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind style based on condition.

Try like this.

.html

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns" (click)="changeButtonStatus();"  [style.color]="col.field == 'defect_target_completion_date'? isDateLess(rowData[col.field]) ? 'red':true:true">
    {{col.field == 'defect_target_completion_date'?  (rowData[col.field] | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'):rowData[col.field]}}
</td>
```

.ts

```
  today = new Date();

  isDateLess(date: any) {
    if (new Date(date) < this.today) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-gfydq6)**

Comment: Fantastic, that did the trick!! I really appreciate the help.